# Is there a difference between !(x is null) and x is object

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

Is there a difference between `!(x is null)` and `x is object`?

Are there cases where they will return different results?

Comment: `!(1 is null)` vs. `1 is object` shows some difference...

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it should not... is not it a difference between two pieces of the code - one compiles, the other does not?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Got your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no appreciable difference. They both compile to the same *CIL*.

Check for yourself [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZYDKA9gLYCm2ANgIYDOzhxBSx6Avu0WkwAWdAFkAFAEp8/bgDdGAJ3QAPdAF50AOxoB3dJVoMWzKQG5ZxBcpbAN6AITi1AS2baArvXrSz3f+iWRNbozMAAZvau7hQARgBWNADGAC7oFlzEfEg8QA==)

<sub>***Note*** : this is the case even with nullable types as you can see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYYDOALgE4CuAxuegMoD2AtgKbYA2AhqaYWIEkxdAF9BRNJgAs6ALIAKAJT5Jolh259SAfnQAPdAF50AO3YB3Jm069+KgNzriANx6V0fYCfQBCRSMAS1Jzai4uVUdRGPQXIndPUmAAM19g0OYAIwArdnp0ZxFiCSQxIA)</sub>

---

From the [Standard ECMA-334 C# Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

> **12.11.11 The is operator**
>
> The is operator is used to check if the run-time type of an object is
>   compatible with a given type. The check is performed at runtime. The
>   result of the operation E is T, where E is an expression and T is a
>   type other than dynamic, **is a Boolean value indicating whether E is
>   non-null and can successfully be converted to type T by a reference
>   conversion, a boxing conversion, an unboxing conversion, a wrapping
>   conversion, or an unwrapping conversion.**

**Update**

To be completely concise and as pointed out by [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov)

`!(1 is null)` vs. `1 is object` shows some difference, the former will not compile due to not being *nullable*

Comment: You forgot to test for the true answer - 42.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov was that a hitchhikers reference ?

Comment: Yes :)... but still `!(42 is null)` behaves differently from `42 is object` (one does not compile) which may be important when writing generics.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ahh yes i see what you mean. updated and attributed